# Splitting raster into smaller chunks using GDAL?

Tags: raster, gdal, grass-gis, dem, open-source-gis

I have a raster (USGS DEM actually) and I need to split it up into smaller chunks like the image below shows. That was accomplished in ArcGIS 10.0 using the Split Raster tool. I would like a FOSS method to do this. I've looked at GDAL, thinking surely it would do it (somehow with gdal_translate), but can't find anything. Ultimately, I'd like to be able to take the raster and say how large (4KM by 4KM chunks) I would like it split up into.

[image]

Comment: I have a utility that uses subprocess.Popen to run multiple gdal translates at the same time which I use for extracting a large raster to tiles using a fishnet, particularly useful if the input and/or output is highly compressed (eg LZW or deflate GeoTiff), if neither is highly compressed the process peaks on HDD access and isn't much faster than running one at a time. Unfortunately it's not generic enough to share due to rigid naming conventions but food for thought anyway. The -multi option for GDALWarp often causes trouble and only uses 2 threads (one read, one write) not all available.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) will work using the -srcwin or -projwin options.

> -srcwin xoff yoff xsize ysize:
>   Selects a subwindow from the source image for copying based on pixel/line location.
>
> -projwin ulx uly lrx lry: Selects a subwindow from the source image
>   for copying (like -srcwin) but with the corners given in georeferenced
>   coordinates.

You would need to come up with the pixel/line locations or corner coordinates and then loop over the values with gdal_translate.  Something like the quick and dirty python below will work if using pixel values and -srcwin is suitable for you, will be a bit more work to sort out with coordinates.

```python
import os, gdal
from gdalconst import *

width = 512
height = 512
tilesize = 64

for i in range(0, width, tilesize):
    for j in range(0, height, tilesize):
        gdaltranString = "gdal_translate -of GTIFF -srcwin "+str(i)+", "+str(j)+", "+str(tilesize)+", " \
            +str(tilesize)+" utm.tif utm_"+str(i)+"_"+str(j)+".tif"
        os.system(gdaltranString)
```

Comment: Hi when I try -projwin option with a geotiff image I get warning saying "Warning: Computed -srcwin -3005000 1879300 50 650 falls completely outside raster extent. Going on however"  I am not sure where I am doing wrong seems like it does not using its georeferenced coordinates.

Comment: @ncelik that is probably because you're using cell coordinates in your projwin and should be using srcwin instead. If you are experiencing difficulty please post a new question with *all* the relevant information so we can make suggestions on your specific problem.

Answer (score 24):

There's a bundled python script specifically for retiling rasters, [gdal_retile](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_retile.html):

```
gdal_retile.py [-v] [-co NAME=VALUE]* [-of out_format] [-ps pixelWidth pixelHeight]
               [-overlap val_in_pixel]
               [-ot  {Byte/Int16/UInt16/UInt32/Int32/Float32/Float64/
                      CInt16/CInt32/CFloat32/CFloat64}]'
               [ -tileIndex tileIndexName [-tileIndexField tileIndexFieldName]]
               [ -csv fileName [-csvDelim delimiter]]
               [-s_srs srs_def]  [-pyramidOnly]
               [-r {near/bilinear/cubic/cubicspline/lanczos}]
               -levels numberoflevels
               [-useDirForEachRow]
               -targetDir TileDirectory input_files
```

e.g:

`gdal_retile.py -ps 512 512 -targetDir C:\example\dir some_dem.tif`

Answer (score 15):

My solution, based on the one from @wwnick reads the raster dimensions from the file itself, and covers the whole image by making the edge tiles smaller if needed:

```python
import os, sys
from osgeo import gdal

dset = gdal.Open(sys.argv[1])

width = dset.RasterXSize
height = dset.RasterYSize

print width, 'x', height

tilesize = 5000

for i in range(0, width, tilesize):
    for j in range(0, height, tilesize):
        w = min(i+tilesize, width) - i
        h = min(j+tilesize, height) - j
        gdaltranString = "gdal_translate -of GTIFF -srcwin "+str(i)+", "+str(j)+", "+str(w)+", " \
            +str(h)+" " + sys.argv[1] + " " + sys.argv[2] + "_"+str(i)+"_"+str(j)+".tif"
        os.system(gdaltranString)
```

Comment: I think it should be sys.argv[1] where it says sys.argv[2], right?

Comment: sys.argv[2] is used as a prefix for the output files, I believe. Super helpful-- thanks @Ries!

Answer (score 6):

For @Aaron who asked:

> I am hoping to find a gdalwarp version of @wwnick's answer that utilizes the -multi option for enhanced multicore and multithreaded operations

*Slight Disclaimer*

This uses `gdalwarp`, though I'm not totally convinced there will be much performance gain. So far I've been I/O bound - running this script on a large raster cutting it into many smaller parts doesn't seem CPU intensive, so I assume the bottleneck is writing to disk. If you're planning on simultaneously re-projecting the tiles or something similar, then this might change. There are tuning tips [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/UserDocs/GdalWarp). A brief play didn't yield any improvement for me, and CPU never seemed to be the limiting factor.

Disclaimer aside, here's a script that will use `gdalwarp` to split up a raster into several smaller tiles. There might be some loss due to the floor division but this can be taken care of by picking the number of tiles you want. It will be `n+1` where `n` is the number you divide by to get the `tile_width` and `tile_height` variables.

```python
import subprocess
import gdal
import sys


def gdalwarp(*args):
    return subprocess.check_call(['gdalwarp'] + list(args))


src_path = sys.argv[1]
ds = gdal.Open(src_path)

try:
    out_base = sys.argv[2]
except IndexError:
    out_base = '/tmp/test_'

gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()

width_px = ds.RasterXSize
height_px = ds.RasterYSize

# Get coords for lower left corner
xmin = int(gt[0])
xmax = int(gt[0] + (gt[1] * width_px))

# get coords for upper right corner
if gt[5] > 0:
    ymin = int(gt[3] - (gt[5] * height_px))
else:
    ymin = int(gt[3] + (gt[5] * height_px))

ymax = int(gt[3])

# split height and width into four - i.e. this will produce 25 tiles
tile_width = (xmax - xmin) // 4
tile_height = (ymax - ymin) // 4

for x in range(xmin, xmax, tile_width):
    for y in range(ymin, ymax, tile_height):
        gdalwarp('-te', str(x), str(y), str(x + tile_width),
                 str(y + tile_height), '-multi', '-wo', 'NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS',
                 '-wm', '500', src_path, out_base + '{}_{}.tif'.format(x, y))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [r.tile](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.tile.html) of GRASS GIS. r.tile generates a separate raster map for each tile with numbered map names based on the user defined prefix. Width of tiles (columns) and height of tiles (rows) can be defined.

Using the [grass-session](https://neteler.gitlab.io/grass-gis-analysis/05_grass_gis_python_session/) Python API only a few lines of Python code are needed to call the r.tile functionality from outside, i.e. to write a standalone script.
Using [r.external](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.external.html) and [r.external.out](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.external.out.html) also no data duplication occurs during the GRASS GIS processing step.

Pseudo code:

1. initialize grass-session
2. define output format with r.external.out
3. link input file with r.external
4. run r.tile which generates the tiles in the format defined above
5. unlink r.external.out
6. close grass-session

Answer (score -1):

```
import gdal
import os

def create_tiles(tile_size, input_filename, in_path='/media/Data/avinash/input/',
           
out_path='/home/nesac/PycharmProjects/GIS_Data_Automation/data/tiles/'):

ds = gdal.Open(in_path + input_filename)

band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)

output_filename = 'tile_'

xsize, ysize = (band.XSize, band.YSize)
tile_size_x, tile_size_y = tile_size
tile_list = {}

complete_x = xsize // tile_size_x
complete_y = ysize // tile_size_y

residue_x = xsize % tile_size_x
residue_y = ysize % tile_size_y

# for part A
for i in range(complete_x):
    for j in range(complete_y):
        Xmin = i * tile_size_x
        Xmax = i * tile_size_x + tile_size_x - 1
        Ymin = j * tile_size_y
        Ymax = j * tile_size_y + tile_size_y - 1
        # do patch creation here
        com_string = "gdal_translate -of GTIFF -srcwin " + str(Xmin) + ", " + str(Ymin) + ", " + str(
            tile_size_x) + ", " + str(tile_size_y) + " " + \
                     str(in_path) + str(input_filename) + " " + str(out_path) + str(output_filename) + str(
            Xmin) + "_" + str(Ymin) + ".tif"
        os.system(com_string)

x_residue_count = 1
y_residue_count = 1

# for part B
for j in range(complete_y):
    Xmin = tile_size_x * complete_x
    Xmax = tile_size_x * complete_x + residue_x - 1
    Ymin = j * tile_size_y
    Ymax = j * tile_size_y + tile_size_y - 1
    # do patch creation here
    com_string = "gdal_translate -of GTIFF -srcwin " + str(Xmin) + ", " + str(Ymin) + ", " + str(
        residue_x) + ", " + str(tile_size_y) + " " + \
                 str(in_path) + str(input_filename) + " " + str(out_path) + str(output_filename) + str(
        Xmin) + "_" + str(Ymin) + ".tif"
    os.system(com_string)

# for part C
for i in range(complete_x):
    Xmin = i * tile_size_x
    Xmax = i * tile_size_x + tile_size_x - 1
    Ymin = tile_size_y * complete_y
    Ymax = tile_size_y * complete_y + residue_y - 1
    com_string = "gdal_translate -of GTIFF -srcwin " + str(Xmin) + ", " + str(Ymin) + ", " + str(
        tile_size_x) + ", " + str(residue_y) + " " + \
                 str(in_path) + str(input_filename) + " " + str(out_path) + str(output_filename) + str(
        Xmin) + "_" + str(Ymin) + ".tif"
    os.system(com_string)

# for part D
Xmin = complete_x * tile_size_x
Ymin = complete_y * tile_size_y
com_string = "gdal_translate -of GTIFF -srcwin " + str(Xmin) + ", " + str(Ymin) + ", " + str(
    residue_x) + ", " + str(residue_y) + " " + \
             str(in_path) + str(input_filename) + " " + str(out_path) + str(output_filename) + str(
    Xmin) + "_" + str(Ymin) + ".tif"
os.system(com_string)
```