# How to cut a raster into smaller, equal area parts?

Tags: qgis, raster, tiles, clip

I have a large raster file that I need to cut into smaller parts.
I already have a polygon shapefile that has the smaller parts that I want to use as an index. The reason for this is that end users will only have to load the tiles they need. The files will be stored on disk.

I would like to cut the raster and have the output files have a suffix of the index. i.e. R1C2

Qgis 2.8 on W7

Comment: This related post may be helpful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/14712/8104

Answer (score 1):

There looks to be a plugin for this:

[gridSplitter](https://github.com/matakuka/gridsplitter/issues)

> gridSplitter
>
> A plugin that cuts a layer into pieces(tiles)
>
> The plugin takes input files (vector or raster) and cuts these into a fixed amount of parts or into fixed-size parts, storing them on the harddisk. There is an option to cut the tiles by predefined shapes (cutlayer). It is not thought for data preparation on pseudo-mercator tiling services, as gdal2tiles already does this job (naming, crs and file storage conventions differ). It is just for "cutting the map into handy bits and leave the map data untouched". The plugin uses GDAL/OGR if found.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like Raster-Extraction-Clipper plugin?? you can give the polygon file as mask layer or you can "play" with the extent (for  the parts you want to cut).

Comment: Do you mean the Gdal tool under Raster>extraction>clipper ?
Because I believe that only cuts one piece at a time. I'm looking to cut all tiles in one run.