# Can I create tiled Qgis2threejs 3D model

Tags: qgis, qgis2threejs

Is able to create 3D model with Qgis2threejs and tiled it for better loading over net?

For example 3D model will be tiled for 100 m X 100 m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

qgis2threejs doesn't offer tiling as built-in functionality

But it can support more than one DEM. If you can tile your DEM, splitting it into one tile per layer, you can add all the DEMs (using 'additional DEMs' settings)

[image]

You could use [gdal_translate and a bit of python to do this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/14717/55203) . There may be other, easier ways to do this, but I can't think of them at the moment.

There are limited options for resolutions in qgis2threejs, so this may make the download times worse, not better :/

Answer (score 1):

No, qgis2threejs does not offer tiling.

Comment: The "add citations" flag can't be serious.