# How to handle large raster datasets in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver

A 16gb large tiff should be processed with the Geoserver. What are the possibilities?

What has already been done:

1) The following tutorial was used:[How to serve very large raster datasets](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/networking-and-servers/9781783287697/2/ch02lvl1sec16/How+to+serve+very+large+raster+datasets) The creation of an ImageMosaic failed.The error message is: *Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:///var/lib/geoserver/Test-TIFF and hints null*

The folder has both write and read rights.The following files are located in this folder: .tiff, .aux, .rrd, and .tfw. Does a file fail to make the plugin work? Or has the Geoserver problems with the file size?

2) In the same tutorial, QGIS is used to create an ImageMosaic. Since there is only one TIFF file, QGIS creates a single tile. That does not take me any further.

3) I tried to build with pyramids (overviews) QGIS. Either an external .ovr file or internal. Here QGIS either crashed or the calculation ran through but no .ovr file was created.

What are the possibilities to display a 16gb tiff with the help of the geoserver?

Comment: a mosaic is many small files joined together so is no use to you when you have one large file. You need to break it up see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14712/splitting-raster-into-smaller-chunks-using-gdal for an example

Comment: Thank you for your hint. With this little script I could solve the problem. (:

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the problem by using the following answer: [Splitting raster into smaller chunks using GDAL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14712/splitting-raster-into-smaller-chunks-using-gdal)

Thanks to iant for the hint.